# How do I filter out attributes that shouldn't be in a POST request in Backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Rails application with the backbone-rails gem. Which works out fine but Backbone tries to send a request with all the attributes of the model. Is there a way I can filter out some of the attributes that will be POST'd on an update/new? This would work great for those virtual attributes and attributes that can't be mass assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in posting attributes that cannot be mass assigned. You will see a warning, but everything will work.

There are basically two ways of actually removing unwanted attributes. The first is to customize the Model's `toJSON()`. For example:

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  function: toJSON() {
    var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
    delete json.somethingIdontWant
    delete json.somethingElse
    return json
  }
})
```

The second, and less clean way, is to explicitly pass the data in your call to `Model.save()`. If you are using the default `Backbone.sync()` method, then this data will be used instead. For example:

```
mything.save({
  data: {just: "the stuff", that: "i want to post"}
})
```

You can probably figure out a way to generalize either of those approaches, depending on which one works for you.

Comment: editing the toJSON isn't that great either, since you usually use that for a templating solution, maybe you need those attributes on the template and not in your server request. i'm not sure myself, but i'd call a separeate function, mything.mysave, and call the save from there with a modified json obj. or something like that.

Comment: Yea. Don't use toJSON both for templates and persistence if you can avoid it.